# How to handle path parametes with hyphen(-) in a FastAPI application?

Tags: fastapi

How to handle path parametes with hyphen(`-`) in FastAPI, as python does not allow hyphen in identifiers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alias` in your definitions. It’s all documented [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#alias-parameters)

As stated in the comments below, if the links stops working here is the code:

```py
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: Union[str, None] = Query(default=None, alias="item-query")):
    results = {"items": [{"item_id": "Foo"}, {"item_id": "Bar"}]}
    if q:
        results.update({"q": q})
    return results
```

Comment: I'd be helpful to include the relevant code in your answer so that the answer is relevant by itself; the URL the answer is pointing to can disappear or be relocated at any time.

Comment: @JarroVGIT could you please do the same with path param and get a response from the server.

Comment: @JarroVGIT python might not allow it. But endpoints does allow hyphen in path params. I have webservices under mulesoft gateway which allowed hyphen in path params. I need to maintain the contract when I rewrite them in fastapi. Also, let's not discuss things which I guess most of the python developers know like hyphen not allowed in python identifiers or things which are already documented on fastapi documentation website. Please let me know if you have a solution to the question